# Repeat position within a loop in xslt

Tags: loops, indexing, numbers, position, xslt-1.0

I have two nested loops. The first loop is picking up distinct value and comparing in second loop. In second loop i am giving position() and it is coming sequential as 1,2,3 but i want it to appear as 1,1,1 during first iteration and 2,2,2 in second iteration and 3,3,3 in third iteration and so on.

XML:

```
<root>
    <Items>
        <Item>
          <ItemCode>12345</ItemCode>
          <ItemColor>Red</ItemColor>
          <Weight>1Kg</Weight>
        </Item>


        <Item>
          <ItemCode>19087</ItemCode>
          <ItemColor>Blue</ItemColor>
          <Weight>1Kg</Weight>
        </Item>
  
    </Items>

<Items>
       
        <Item>
          <ItemCode>12345</ItemCode>
          <ItemColor>Yellow</ItemColor>
          <Weight>1Kg</Weight>
        </Item>

        <Item>
          <ItemCode>19087</ItemCode>
          <ItemColor>Green</ItemColor>
          <Weight>1Kg</Weight>
        </Item>
    
    </Items>
</root>
```

Required Output:

```
  12345
  1.Red
  1.Yellow
  
  19087
  2.Blue
  2.Green

(Or)
  1.12345
    Red
    Yellow
  
  2.19087
    Blue
    Green
```

Code:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="check" match="Items" use="ItemCode" />

<xsl:template match="root/Items">
     <xsl:for-each select="Item[count(. | key('check', ItemCode)[1]) = 1]">
             <xsl:value-of select="ItemCode"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('check', ItemCode)"> 
               
               <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
               <xsl:value-of select="ItemColor"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using xslt-1.0
Your help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Store the position in variable while in the context of the outer loop. If you cannot make it work, post a [mcve] showing an input, your attempted XSLT and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-code" match="Item" use="ItemCode"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="Items/Item[count(. | key('item-by-code', ItemCode)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ItemCode"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('item-by-code', ItemCode)"> 
            <xsl:text>&#10;  </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ItemColor"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied yo your input example, will return:

**Result**

```
1.12345
  Red
  Yellow

2.19087
  Blue
  Green
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-code" match="Item" use="ItemCode"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="Items/Item[count(. | key('item-by-code', ItemCode)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="ItemCode"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('item-by-code', ItemCode)"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ItemColor"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

```
12345
1.Red
1.Yellow

19087
2.Blue
2.Green
```

Comment: I have modified my answer to fit your edited input. It's a trivial adjustment which you should have been able to do yourself. Next time, please do not change your question after it has been answered.